# Sending messages in bulk to APNS, what happens if there is an error with some of them?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Let's say I have 3 notifications to send - `a`, `b` and `c` - but there is a problem with notification `b`. Let's assume it is an invalid token. If I do the following:

1. Create buffer
2. Add a,b and c to buffer
3. Send buffer to APNS server

Will message `c` be sent?

The Apple documentation says:

> If you send a notification and APNs finds the notification malformed
>   or otherwise unintelligible, it returns an error-response packet prior
>   to disconnecting.

Does this mean that I would receive an error about `b` and the connection would be dropped, and therefore `c` would never be sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Message `c` would never be sent. If you manage to receive the error response for message `b`, you have to resend all the messages you sent after sending `b` and before receiving the response.

You can read a good article about it here : [The Problem with APNS](http://redth.info/the-problem-with-apples-push-notification-ser/)