# APNS - Failed to send message

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I got strange problem with APNS. I using com.notnoop.apns library and when i try to push same message to 40 devices, i got

```
ApnsConnectionImpl : Failed to send message 
com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@be443877... trying again
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
...
```

All going fine, when i try to push same message to 4, 10 even 15 devices.

I try to split collection with push tokens from 40 to 4*10 and push this notification in foreach, but with second try i get same problem.

This is code with push method:

```
//prepared collection and message
private void sendMessage(Collection<String> ids, PayloadBuilder message) {
try{
    service.push(ids, message.build);       
}catch(Exception e) {
    logger.debug("APNS ERROR : size of collection - " + ids.size());
}
```

}

Constructor of service:

```
  try {
        service = APNS.newService()
                .withCert(pathToCertificate, certificatePasswd)
                .withProductionDestination()
                .build();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I lunch this method 10 times with different Collections of push tokens (collections got random from 1 to 40 tokens)  and one time i got this exception (all of tokens was right). It is possible to get reset connection by APNS for no reason? If i lost connection, what suppose to do? Reconnect and try push one more time lost messages to devices? Please help, im out of ideas.

Comment: Are you sure all the tokens are valid? The most likely reason for this error is that at least one of them is not valid. A token that is valid for the sandbox (development) environment is not valid for the production environment and vice versa.

Comment: yes, im absolutely sure. All of tokens i got in my database and no one have a bad format, length or even isnt a null. I try to catch this exception, recreate service object and retry to push for this tokens, where i get exception. Maybe this will works.

Comment: The fact that all the tokens in your DB have the correct length doesn't mean they are all valid. Even if all the tokens in your DB were received from Apple, they can still be invalid, since every token is invalid if used in the wrong environment (as mentioned in my previous commment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend Java PNS library: http://code.google.com/p/javapns/. I used it in one of my projects and it works fine.

Comment: Great thx pawelqus.. i change only library and all starts work fine. So my question is, why notnoop generate this strange exception for this same tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have invalid device tokens in your DB.

Here are some similar questions that can help you :

[Validating Device Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842597/validate-apn-push-token/14843528#14843528)

[Another One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715921/critical-outcome-when-sending-push-notification-from-our-server/14716564#14716564)

[One More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185842/push-notification-not-delivering-on-multiple-devices-in-iphone-app/14188046#14188046)

[Last One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848970/sending-messages-in-bulk-to-apns-what-happens-if-there-is-an-error-with-some-of/13770897#13770897)

In addition, you should read this great article about [the problem with Apple Push Notification Service](http://redth.info/the-problem-with-apples-push-notification-ser/).